# Filtering out similar questions based on tag

Tags: feature-request, asking

When you type out a new question title, se tries to show similar questions.  I propose that, after adding a tag in, it filters "related questions" based on your tag.

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91568/feedback-requested-similar-questions-displayed-in-sidebar-on-ask it is used, but I think the weighting might not be sufficient for our purposes.